python, Telethon. Закрывает все сессии авторизаций после выполнения кода
Это рабочий код, который выводит id и username из последних 200 пользователей (кроме скрытых), вступивших в телеграмм группу.
Но после выполнения кода все сессии авторизации закрываются. Словно получаю блокировку от телеграмма. Помогите, как это исправить?
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
import time

api_id = '87654321'
api_hash = '111222333444555666777888999000'
phone_number = '+123456789'
channel_username = 'name_group'

client = TelegramClient(phone_number, api_id, api_hash)


with client:
    channel = client.get_entity(channel_username)
    members = client.get_participants(channel)
    for member in members:
        if member.username is not None:
            print(member.id, ';', member.username)
            time.sleep(1)


print('END')


Нужно было указать дополнительные параметры в конструкторе класса TelegramClient.
Конечный код выглядит так:
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
import time

# Получить api_id, api_hash
# https://my.telegram.org/apps
api_id = 87654321
api_hash = 'aaa222BBB444ccc666DDD888eee000'
phone_number = '+123456789'
channel_username = 'name_group'

client = TelegramClient(phone_number, api_id, api_hash,
                        system_version='1.2.3-zxc-custom',
                        device_model='aboba-linux-custom',
                        app_version='1.0.1')

with client:
    # запись в файл 
    file = open(r'OUT.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8")
    channel = client.get_entity(channel_username)
    members = client.get_participants(channel)
    for member in members:
        # смотри 200 последних вступивших пользователей (ограничение тг)
        if member.username is not None:
            # не выводить тех, чей username скрыт
            # id, username, first_name, last_name, phone
            print(member.id, ';', member.username)
            file.write(str(member.id) + ';' + member.username + '\n')
            time.sleep(0.01)

file.close()
print('END')

